# Web audio synthesis API?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web

Is there a  web audio API for generating sounds with something like General MIDI synthesis?  I just need simple clicks or pitches.  The only web audio documentation I can find is for playback of embedded mp3/wav files, which I don't think is an ideal approach for what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find [Tone.js](http://tonejs.org/docs/Tone.html) helpful

On Github here: https://github.com/TONEnoTONE/Tone.js

also checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b208cbf8b12fdf23d91) on javascript audio synthesis. Make sure to click the link to codepen and read the article article accompanying it.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it might fit the bill.  It even has a [.midi file parser](https://github.com/TONEnoTONE/Tone.js/blob/master/utils/MidiToScore.js).  I'll have to spend some time with this.

Answer (score 2):

In Web Audio API you have the Oscillator Node to create your own sounds as a synth.

Here you have a very good introduction:

http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2013/06/05/playing-notes-web-audio-api.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for that, but it's not supported on all browsers ([support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api)).
It's called Web Audio API, here's a link to samples from MDN: [Web Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API)

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that before, but, like you point out, it seems very new,  and more abstract than what I was hoping for.  All the tutorial articles for it I found focus on sample-based audio, which I'm trying to avoid, for now.